# Unable to login Portal community after activating Critical update

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

Before I activated the critical update name 'Restrict Access to @AuraEnabled Apex Methods for Guest and Portal Users Based on User Profile' I can login to Portal community properly.

After I Activated that critical update, community user can not login to Portal and the error message in response of Network tab will be 'You do not have access to the Apex class named `LightningLoginFormController`

I am sure that guest or portal user profile can access `LightningLoginFormController` Apex class.

```
global class LightningLoginFormController {

    public LightningLoginFormController() {

    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String login(String username, String password, String startUrl) {
        try{
            ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
            aura.redirect(lgn);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();            
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean getIsUsernamePasswordEnabled() {
        Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = getAuthConfig();
        return authConfig.getUsernamePasswordEnabled();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean getIsSelfRegistrationEnabled() {
        Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = getAuthConfig();
        return authConfig.getSelfRegistrationEnabled();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getSelfRegistrationUrl() {
        Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = getAuthConfig();
        if (authConfig.getSelfRegistrationEnabled()) {
            return authConfig.getSelfRegistrationUrl();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getForgotPasswordUrl() {
        Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = getAuthConfig();
        return authConfig.getForgotPasswordUrl();
    }

    @TestVisible
    private static Auth.AuthConfiguration getAuthConfig(){
        Id networkId = Network.getNetworkId();
        Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = new Auth.AuthConfiguration(networkId,'');
        return authConfig;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    global static String setExperienceId(String expId) {
        // Return null if there is no error, else it will return the error message 
        try {
            if (expId != null) {
                Site.setExperienceId(expId);
            }
            return null; 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();            
        }
    }   
}
```

Does someone else face the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly allow access to Apex classes containing @AuraEnabled methods.
Guest, portal, or community user can access an @AuraEnabled Apex method only when the user’s profile or an assigned permission set allows access to the Apex class.

More details here:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_guest_users.htm